# App Engine Cloud Endpoints Frameworks (Java) - NullPointerException when run locally

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I've followed the directions for the [Quickstart for Cloud Endpoints Frameworks on App Engine (Java)](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java), and everything works except running it locally.  When I run `mvn appengine:run` I receive failure messages, receive only 503's for the /_ah/start (with endless automatic retries), and I see a NullPointerException stacktrace.  I'm seeing:

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: May 28, 2017 10:14:35 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
[INFO] GCLOUD: WARNING: failed endpoints-api-configuration: java.lang.NullPointerException
[INFO] GCLOUD: May 28, 2017 10:14:35 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
[INFO] GCLOUD: WARNING: Failed startup of context com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@45b4c3a9{/,/Users/clay/java-docs-samples/appengine/endpoints-frameworks-v2/backend/target/echo-1.0-SNAPSHOT}
[INFO] GCLOUD: java.lang.NullPointerException
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityServicePb$GetAccessTokenResponse$Builder.setAccessToken(AppIdentityServicePb.java:6221)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.dev.LocalAppIdentityService.getAccessToken(LocalAppIdentityService.java:160)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.callInternal(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:541)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:484)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:461)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable$1.run(Executors.java:533)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable.call(Executors.java:530)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried on a separate system / OS and received the same results.  Did I miss something?  Or did something get changed and the docs haven't been updated yet?  Being able to debug locally is pretty important

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Followed step by step and am getting the same failure: NullPointerException when trying to set the access token and a repeating 503 error. Also getting an error message about the working directory not being the same as the web application root.

Comment: I'm have the exact same problem. I'm still fighting with it. I think it has something to do with using java 8. You have java 8 installed yeah?

Comment: Can you run `gcloud auth application-default login` and try again?

Comment: @saiyr That did it. Can you post as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @shadyhossin Yeah I have java 8 installed.  Could be a factor, but give saiyr's comment a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `gcloud auth application-default login` to fix this issue. I will update the official docs. Apologies for any inconvenience!